# Java - JList see if ANYTHING is selected

Tags: java, swing

How do I check if a user has anything selected inside a JList?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried `JList.isSelectionEmpty()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal, but...

Create a deep copy of the list before it gets changed. Then compare (using equals) the possibly changed list to the copy of the original.